# Convert C++ to Java (pointers removed by me already (simplified))

Tags: java, c++

I need to convert some C++ code to Java.

The C++ code I was given had pointers and was rather complex. I've been able to simplify the C++ code to something that can be converted into java now but I don't know how to convert it to java.

I have simplified it so I'm not just asking for you to do the homework or anything.

```
void encryptDecrypt(byte *data, dword length, byte *key)
{
    byte v3, v5, v6;
    int len = length;

    if(len > 0)
    {
        do
        {
            --len;
            v3 = (byte)(*(dword *)key + 1);
            *(dword *)key = (dword)v3;
            v5 = (byte)(*(dword *)(key + 4) + *(byte *)(key + 8 + v3));
            *(dword *)(key + 4) = (dword)v5;
            v6 = *(byte *)(key + 8 + v3);
            *(byte *)(key + 8 + v3) = *(byte *)(key + 8 + v5);
            *(byte *)(key + 8 + *(dword *)(key + 4)) = v6;

            *(byte *)data++ ^=
                *(byte *)(key + 8 + (byte)(*(byte *)(key + 8 + *(dword *)(key + 4)) + *(byte *)(key + 8 + *(dword *)key)));
            data[length - len - 1] ^= key[8 + key[8 + ((dword *)key)[1]] + key[8 + ((dword *)key)[0]]];
        }
        while(len);
    }
}
```

That was pretty complex and converting it to java like that is kinda very hard.
I simplified it to the following:

```
void encryptDecrypt(byte *data, dword length, byte *key)
{
    byte v3, v5, v6;
    int len = length;

    if(len > 0)
    {
        do
        {
            --len;
            v3 = key[0] + 1;
            key[0] = v3;
            v5 = key[4] + key[8 + v3];
            key[4] = v5;
            v6 = key[8 + v3];
            key[8 + v3] = key[8 + v5];
            key[8 + key[4]] = v6;

            data[length - len - 1] ^= key[8 + (byte)(key[8 + key[4]] + key[8 + key[0]])];
        }
        while(len);
    }
}
```

But Now I'm not sure about getting the simplified version to something that will work in java.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: where are you stucked while converting?

Comment: for one variable dont use * they use [], instead of `byte *data` it would be `byte[] data`

Comment: I'm not sure how to convert it because I don't use C++ much.

Comment: @user2693587 is that the only change needed?

Comment: well ^= shouldn't work, but I don't know what it means in c++, what does it do?

Comment: @user2693587 it's an xor assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work just fine.

```
public void encryptDecrypt(byte[] data, int length, byte[] key)
        {
            byte v3, v5, v6;
            int len = length;

            if(len > 0)
            {
                do
                {
                    --len;
                    v3 = (byte) (key[0] + 1);
                    key[0] = v3;
                    v5 = (byte) (key[4] + key[8 + v3]);
                    key[4] = v5;
                    v6 = key[8 + v3];
                    key[8 + v3] = key[8 + v5];
                    key[8 + key[4]] = v6;

                    data[length - len - 1] ^= key[8 + (byte)(key[8 + key[4]] + key[8 + key[0]])];
                }
                while(len > 0);
            }
        }
```

But you could still change many things, like the `do {}` isn't needed in java.

Answer (score 0):

should be something like:

```
public void encryptDecrypt(byte[] data, int length, byte[] key)
{
    byte v3, v5, v6;
    int len = length;

    if(len > 0)
    {
        do
        {
            --len;
            v3 = key[0] + 1;
            key[0] = v3;
            v5 = key[4] + key[8 + v3];
            key[4] = v5;
            v6 = key[8 + v3];
            key[8 + v3] = key[8 + v5];
            key[8 + key[4]] = v6;

            data[length - len - 1] ^= key[8 + (byte)(key[8 + key[4]] + key[8 + key[0]])];
        }
        while(len);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt length be a long since java doesnt have unsigned ints?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik java doesn't concdern signed and unsigned variables

Comment: ` v3 = key[0] + 1;` and the v5 = have an error where it says possible lossy conversion from int to byte

Comment: But if you are using them for decrement like "--len" then it would count for half times when using signed versions with len>0 comparison.